# Why does Ignite UI Hierarchical Grid throw a NullReferenceException when I add a layout?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, infragistics, ignite-ui, iggrid

Whenever I load the grid without adding a layout the parent grid loads just fine. However, whenever I add the layout, A NullReferenceException is thrown when binding data to the parent.

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        GridModel grid = GridLoadOnDemandModel();
        grid.ID = "Services";
        grid.LoadOnDemand = true;
        grid.DataSourceUrl = this.Url.Action("BindParent");
        grid.ColumnLayouts[0].DataSourceUrl = this.Url.Action("BindChild");
        return View(grid);
    }

    private GridModel GridLoadOnDemandModel()
    {
        GridModel grid = new GridModel();
        grid.AutoGenerateLayouts = false;
        grid.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        grid.PrimaryKey = "ID";
        grid.Width = "100%";
        grid.Columns.Add(new GridColumn() { HeaderText = "Service ID", Key = "ID", DataType = "number" });
        grid.Columns.Add(new GridColumn() { HeaderText = "Client ID", Key = "ClientID", DataType = "number" });
        grid.Columns.Add(new GridColumn() { HeaderText = "Package ID", Key = "PackageID", DataType = "number" });

        GridColumnLayoutModel layout = new GridColumnLayoutModel();
        layout.Key = "ServiceHistory";
        layout.ForeignKey = "ID";
        layout.PrimaryKey = "ID";
        layout.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        layout.Columns.Add(new GridColumn() { HeaderText = "Log ID", Key = "LogID", DataType = "number", Hidden = true });
        layout.Columns.Add(new GridColumn() { HeaderText = "Service ID", Key = "ID", DataType = "number", Hidden = true});
        layout.Columns.Add(new GridColumn() { HeaderText = "Client ID", Key = "ClientID", DataType = "number" });
        layout.Columns.Add(new GridColumn() { HeaderText = "Package ID", Key = "PackageID", DataType = "number" });

        layout.Width = "100%";
        grid.ColumnLayouts.Add(layout);

        return grid;
    }
```

The error is thrown in the BindParent method on the GetData method.

```
    public JsonResult BindParent()
    {
        GridModel model = GridLoadOnDemandModel();
        model.DataSource = GetService().AsQueryable();
        return model.GetData();
    }

    public JsonResult BindChild(string path, string layout)
    {
        GridModel model = GridLoadOnDemandModel();
        model.DataSource = GetServiceLogs().AsQueryable();
        return model.GetData(path, layout);
    }

    private IEnumerable<Service> GetService()
    {
        var services = new List<Service>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            var service = new Service
            {
                ID = i,
                ClientID = 1,
                PackageID = 1
            };

            services.Add(service);
        }

        return services;
    }

    private IEnumerable<ServiceLog> GetServiceLogs()
    {
        var serviceLogs = new List<ServiceLog>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            var serviceLog = new ServiceLog
            {
                LogID = i,
                ID = 1,
                ClientID = i,
                PackageID = i
            };

            serviceLogs.Add(serviceLog);
        }

        return serviceLogs;
    } 
public class Service
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int ClientID { get; set; }
    public int PackageID { get; set; }
}

public class ServiceLog
{
    public int LogID { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int ClientID { get; set; }
    public int PackageID { get; set; }
}

public class Service
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int ClientID { get; set; }
    public int PackageID { get; set; }
}

public class ServiceLog
{
    public int LogID { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int ClientID { get; set; }
    public int PackageID { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the stack trace:

at Infragistics.Web.Mvc.GridModel.RenderHierarchicalQueryableRecursive(IQueryable queryable, WrappedGridResponse response, GridModel baseLayout)
   at Infragistics.Web.Mvc.GridModel.RenderHierarchicalQueryable(IQueryable queryable)
   at Infragistics.Web.Mvc.GridModel.DataBind()
   at Infragistics.Web.Mvc.GridModel.GetData()
   at IgniteUIHTMLEditorExample.Controllers.ServiceHistoryController.BindParent() in c:\Users\kyle.wingate\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\IgniteUIHTMLEditorExample\IgniteUIHTMLEditorExample\Controllers\ServiceHistoryController.cs:line 53
   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.ActionInvocation.InvokeSynchronousActionMethod()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End[TResult](IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.b__3d()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `Service` class/model you should have a property named after the `GridColumnLayoutModel.Key` value. Here is how the `Service` class should look:

```
public class Service
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int ClientID { get; set; }
    public int PackageID { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ServiceLog>  ServiceHistory { get; set; }
}
```

This change will resolve the `NullReferenceException`, but there are some more changes that you need to make so that your sample runs as expected.

You should also correctly configure the `GridColumnLayoutModel.PrimaryKey` and `GridColumnLayoutModel.ForeignKey`, because the `GridModel.GetData` depends on them to extract/filter the correct child records.
I guess in your case the configuration for the `ServiceHistory` layout should look like this:

```
//… code omitted
layout.ForeignKey = "ID";
layout.PrimaryKey = "LogID";
// … code omitted
```

With this change the `GridModel.GetData` method will filter the data by the `ID` property in the `ServiceLog` class.

You may need to change the `GetServiceLogs` method to generate different `ID`, because right now it will return data only for `Service` with `ID = 1`